# How do I add threads from these codes because I want to have multiple users to make a chat program?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, client-server

SampleClient.java - does all the client stuff

```
package sampleclient;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SampleClient extends JFrame{

private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream user;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input; //from the server
private String message = "";
private String serverIP;
private Socket connection;
private String name;
private JTextArea contacts;
private PrintWriter toS;

//constructor
public SampleClient(String host, String username){
    super("Client");
    serverIP = host;
    name = username;
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false); //not allowed to type while no one is connected
    userText.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                userText.setText("");

            }

        }
        );
    add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    contacts = new JTextArea();
    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    add(new JScrollPane(contacts), BorderLayout.EAST); //scroll
    contacts.append("   ONLINE CONTACTS   \n");
    add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER); //scroll
    setSize(300, 150);
    setVisible(true);
}

//connect to server
public void startRunning(){
    try {

        connectServer();
        setupStreams();
        whileChatting();

    }catch(EOFException eofException){
        showMessage("\n Client terminated connection");
    }catch (IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        closeAll();
    }
}

//connectServer
private void connectServer() throws IOException{
    showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789); //passes to an IP Adrdress and Port Number
    showMessage("Connected to:" + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName()); //prompt
    toS = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);
    toS.println(name);

}

//set up streams for sending and receive the messages
private void setupStreams()throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); //receive messages
    showMessage("\n Streams are connected");

}

//actual chat
private void whileChatting()throws IOException{
    ableToType(true);
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" +message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
            showMessage("\n ERROR!");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
}

//close sockets and streams
private void closeAll(){
    showMessage("\n Closing connections..");
    ableToType(false);
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//send messages to server
private void sendMessage(String message){
    try{
        System.out.println(name);
        output.writeObject( "\n" + name + ": " + message);
        output.flush(); //push bytes
        showMessage("\n" + name + ": " + message);

    }catch(IOException ioException){
        chatWindow.append("ERROR!");

    }
}

//Update chatWindow
private void showMessage(final String m){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    chatWindow.append(m); //appear at the end of the conversation

                }
            }
    );

}

//permission to type to for user
private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    userText.setEditable(tof);
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

clientTest.java

```
    package sampleclient;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class ClientTest {

        public String userName;
        private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Messenger");

            private static String getUsername() {
            return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                frame,
                "Enter Username:",
                "Instant Messenger",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){

            String username = getUsername();//getting username
            SampleClient client;                     
            client = new SampleClient("10.0.1.4", username); //localhost

            client.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            client.startRunning();
        }

    }
```

SampleServer.java - does all the server stuff

```
        package sampleserver;

        import java.io.*;
        import java.net.*;
        import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.util.*;
        import java.lang.Object.*;


        public class SampleServer extends JFrame{

            private JTextField userText; //message variable area
            private JTextArea chatWindow; //display the conversation
            private ObjectOutputStream output; //output stream->flows from my computer to the other computer
            private ObjectInputStream input; //input stream->receive stuff
            private ObjectInputStream name; //input stream->receive stuff
            private ServerSocket server; //server variable
            private Socket connection; //socket variable
            private Vector<String> users;
            private Vector<String> ips;
            private JTextArea conList;
            private PrintWriter p;
            private BufferedReader fromC;

            //constructor
            public SampleServer(){
                super("Instant Messenger");
                userText = new JTextField(); //text field
                userText.setEditable(false); //not allowed to type anything if there are no online
                userText.addActionListener(
                        new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
                                sendMessage(event.getActionCommand()); //sends the message
                                userText.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                );
                add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                users = new Vector();
                ips = new Vector();
                chatWindow = new JTextArea();
                conList = new JTextArea();
                conList.setEditable(false);
                add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
                add(new JScrollPane(conList), BorderLayout.EAST);
                conList.append("   ONLINE USERS    \n");
                setSize(300, 150);
                setVisible(true);
            }

           //set up and run the server
           public void startRunning(){
               try {
                   server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100); //port number and only 100 can connect to the server
                   while(true){
                       try{
                           //connect and have conversation to other client
                           waitForConnection(); //waiting method
                           setupStreams(); //set up output and input stream
                           whileChatting(); //actual chat

                       }catch(EOFException eofException){
                           showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
                       }finally {
                           closeAll();
                       }
                   }

               }catch(IOException ioException){
                   ioException.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

           //wait for connection, then display connection information
           private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
               showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect...\n");
               connection = server.accept(); //once someone asked for connection, accepts this
               //showMessage("Now connected to "+connection.getInetAddress().getHostName()); //converts the ip address to string

               ips.add(connection.getInetAddress().getHostName()); // adds ip address of client to ips vector

               fromC = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); // gets what client sent through printwriter - username
               String s = new String(fromC.readLine()); // saves as string
               users.add(s); // saves username of client to users vector
               String con = (connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
               showMessage(s + " / " + con + " has connected.");

               Iterator c = users.iterator(); // username iterator
               Iterator b = ips.iterator(); // ip address iterator

               while(c.hasNext()) {

                   String d = (c.next()).toString(); // gets next element in users vector
                   String e = (b.next().toString()); // gets next element in ips vector
                   conList.append(d + "\n"); // displays username in online users list
                   conList.append("(" + e + ")\n\n"); // displays ip in online users list
               }

           }

           //get stream to send and receive data
           private void setupStreams()throws IOException{
               output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); //computer who we communicate to
               output.flush(); //bytes of information that is send to other person (leftover)
               input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); //receive messages
               showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");



           }

           //actual chat conversation
           private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
               String message = "You are now connected!";
               sendMessage(message); 
               ableToType(true);
               do{
                   try{
                       message = (String) input.readObject(); //views it as an object and make sure it's a string
                       showMessage("\n" + message);
                   }catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException){
                       showMessage("\nError!");
                   }
               }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));

           }

           //close streams and sockets 
           private void closeAll(){
               showMessage("\n Closing connection... \n");
               ableToType(false);
               try{
                   output.close();
                   input.close();
                   connection.close();
               }catch(IOException ioException){
                   ioException.printStackTrace();

               }
           }

           //send message to other computer
           private void sendMessage(String message){
               try{
                   output.writeObject("SERVER - " +message); //sends the mesage to the output stream
                   output.flush(); //push extra bytes to user
                   showMessage("\n SERVER - " + message);
               }catch(IOException ioException){
                   chatWindow.append("\n ERROR!"); //put in the chat area

               }

           }

           //updates chatWindow
           private void showMessage(final String text){
               SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //updats GUI or threads
                       new Runnable(){
                           public void run(){
                               chatWindow.append(text); //add string at the end of the chatWindow
                           }
                       }
               );

           }

           //allow user to type
           private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //updats GUI or threads
                       new Runnable(){
                           public void run(){
                              userText.setEditable(tof); //updates the GUI
                           }
                       }
               );
           }

        }
```

serverTest.java

```
        package sampleserver;

        import javax.swing.JFrame;

        public class serverTest {
            public static void main(String[] args){
                SampleServer server = new SampleServer();
                server.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                server.startRunning();
            }
        }
```

The problem is that we have to do a client-client program and what we did was there are 2 laptops, one for opening the client and server and one for only the client. the 2 laptops successfully connected (client-server) but the client of the laptop with the server can't connect to the chat. Though, if the client of the 2nd laptop is closed, the 1st laptop can connect to its server. Help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you programmed the chat application for only one computer, as it doesn't create a new `Thread` for each client, and goes into a while loop until the client disconnects.

```
//connect and have conversation to other client
waitForConnection(); //waiting method
setupStreams(); //set up output and input stream
whileChatting(); //actual chat //The problem is here, this should have been in a new Thread
```

Change your SampleServer.java to:

```
package sampleserver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;


public class SampleServer{

    private ObjectOutputStream output; //output stream->flows from my computer to the other computer
    private ObjectInputStream input; //input stream->receive stuff
    private ObjectInputStream name; //input stream->receive stuff
    private Socket connection; //socket variable
    private String user;
    private String ip;
    private PrintWriter p;
    private BufferedReader fromC;
    private serverTest server; //Saves the server test to append messages.

    //constructor
    public SampleServer(Socket c, String username, String userip, serverTest t){  //EDITED!!
        connection = c;
        server = t;
        ip= userip;
        user= username;             
        setupStreams(); //set up output and input stream
    }

    public void run() //This method gets called when Thread starts running
    {
        whileChatting();
        closeAll();
    }

   //get stream to send and receive data
   private void setupStreams(){
       try{
       output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); //computer who we communicate to
       output.flush(); //bytes of information that is send to other person (leftover)
       input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); //receive messages
       showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");
       }catch(IOException ioException){
           ioException.printStackTrace();

       }
   }

   //actual chat conversation
   private void whileChatting(){
       String message = "You are now connected!";
       sendMessage(message); 
       do{
           try{
               message = (String) input.readObject(); //views it as an object and make sure it's a string
               showMessage("\n" + message);
           }catch(Exception e){
               //showMessage("\nError!");
           }
       }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));

   }

   //close streams and sockets 
   public void closeAll(){
       showMessage("\n Closing connection... \n");
       try{
           output.close();
           input.close();
           connection.close();
       }catch(IOException ioException){
           ioException.printStackTrace();

       }
   }

   //send message to other computer
   public void sendMessage(String message){
       try{
           output.writeObject("SERVER - " +message); //sends the mesage to the output stream
           output.flush(); //push extra bytes to user
       }catch(IOException ioException){
           showMessage("\n ERROR!"); //put in the chat area

       }

   }

   //updates chatWindow
   private void showMessage(String text){
       server.showMessage(text);
   }
}
```

And change your serverTest.java to:

```
    package sampleserver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;

public class serverTest extends JFrame {
    private JTextField userText; //message variable area
    private JTextArea chatWindow; //display the conversation
    private ServerSocket server; //server variable
    private Vector<String> users;
    private Vector<String> ips;
    private JTextArea conList;
    private ArrayList<SampleServer> connections = new ArrayList<SampleServer>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new serverTest();
    }

    public serverTest()
    {
        super("Instant Messenger");
        userText = new JTextField(); //text field
        userText.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
                        sendMessage(event.getActionCommand()); //sends the message
                        userText.setText("");
                    }
                }
        );
        add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        users = new Vector();
        ips = new Vector();
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        conList = new JTextArea();
        conList.setEditable(false);
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
        add(new JScrollPane(conList), BorderLayout.EAST);
        conList.append("   ONLINE USERS    \n");
        setSize(300, 150);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

       try {
           server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100); //port number and only 100 can connect to the server
           while(true){
               try{
                    showMessage("Waiting for someone to connect...\n");
                    Socket connection = server.accept(); //once someone asked for connection, accepts this
                    //showMessage("Now connected to "+connection.getInetAddress().getHostName()); //converts the ip address to string

                    ips.add(connection.getInetAddress().getHostName()); // adds ip address of client to ips vector

                    BufferedReader fromC = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); // gets what client sent through printwriter - username
                    String s = new String(fromC.readLine()); // saves as string
                    users.add(s); // saves username of client to users vector
                    String con = (connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
                    showMessage(s + " / " + con + " has connected.");

                    Iterator c = users.iterator(); // username iterator
                    Iterator b = ips.iterator(); // ip address iterator

                    conList.setText("");

                    while(c.hasNext()) {

                        String d = (c.next()).toString(); // gets next element in users vector
                        String e = (b.next().toString()); // gets next element in ips vector
                        conList.append(d + "\n"); // displays username in online users list
                        conList.append("(" + e + ")\n\n"); // displays ip in online users list
                    }
                    final SampleServer se = new SampleServer(connection, s, con, this);
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run()
                        {
                            se.run();
                        }
                    });
                    connections.add(se);
               }catch(EOFException eofException){
                   showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
               }
           }

       }catch(IOException ioException){
           ioException.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    public void closeAll()
    {
        while (!connections.isEmpty())
        {
            connections.get(0).closeAll();
            connections.remove(0);
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String text)
    {
                showMessage("\n SERVER - " + text);
        for (SampleServer s : connections)
        {
            s.sendMessage(text);
        }
    }

    public void showMessage(final String text)
    {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater( //updats GUI or threads
               new Runnable(){
                   public void run(){
                       chatWindow.append(text); //add string at the end of the chatWindow
                   }
               }
       );
    }
}
```

Here I moved the GUI code to the main class, and also moved the serversocket to the main class, and made the SampleServer have only one user. When it recieves a message, it adds it to the GUI.
Only the server can send messages, and the server doesn't send the clients the user list.

Comment: what is the mechanism which enables this to work for multiple computers?

Comment: @Thufir The original code didn't create a new `Thread` for each client, and so could only serve one client at a time, because when a client connected, the code went into a `while` loop until the client disconnects.